# Oracle day of week (without string comparison)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'll preface this saying all the documentation I find either doesn't apply to my oracle version:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51711_01/DR/WeekDay.html;
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37483_01/server.751/es_eql/src/ceql_functions_date_extract.html

or the reference for functions I can use don't mention day of week:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm#SQLRF00639

and so I'm only finding ways to do this using [to_char](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm#SQLRF00639) and then doing varchar2 compares. I would like to just stick to date formatting, if at all possible.

here is my sql so far

```
select dateSold from sales
where extract(dateSold, day_of_week) in (1, 3, 4, 7)

SQL Error: ORA-00904: "DAY_OF_WEEK": invalid identifier
```

Comment: The first link is for Document Automation Language (DAL). The second link is for Oracle Endeca Server. (I've never heard of either of those). Oracle has documentation for all their products on the same site which can be a bit confusing when searching for things, but you should only referring to the RDBMS documentation, as in your third link, which is for 11gR1 - use the documentation for the DB version you're working on. [This might be a useful place to start](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/index.html) as you can pick the right version from the drop-down list.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for commenting on the various documentation links. I was also confused by the second link above, especially since postgreSQL does support `day-of-week`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `to_char()` to get the day number, but you can convert that to a number:

```
select dateSold, sum(quantity) from sales
where to_number(to_char(dateSold, 'D')) in (1, 3, 4, 7)
```

But `D` is NLS-dependent, so you'll get different results if you run this is in a session that's in, say, the USA versus on in the France. Which might be why you've seen string comparisons, as you can at least control that more:

```
select dateSold, sum(quantity) from sales
where to_char(dateSold, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') in ('MON', 'WED', 'THU', 'SUN')
```

---

To see the difference NLS settings make, this shows `D` and `DY` values for the same data and query as if run in the USA:

```
alter session set nls_territory = 'AMERICA';
alter session set nls_language = 'ENGLISH';

with cte (dateSold) as (
  select date '2018-08-01' + level - 1 from dual connect by level <= 7
)
select dateSold,
  to_number(to_char(dateSold, 'D')) as d,
  to_char(dateSold, 'DY') as dy,
  to_char(dateSold, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') as dy_english
from cte;

DATESOLD           D DY           DY_ENGLISH  
--------- ---------- ------------ ------------
01-AUG-18          4 WED          WED         
02-AUG-18          5 THU          THU         
03-AUG-18          6 FRI          FRI         
04-AUG-18          7 SAT          SAT         
05-AUG-18          1 SUN          SUN         
06-AUG-18          2 MON          MON         
07-AUG-18          3 TUE          TUE
```

and then as if run in France:

```
alter session set nls_territory = 'FRANCE';
alter session set nls_language = 'FRENCH';

with cte (dateSold) as (
  select date '2018-08-01' + level - 1 from dual connect by level <= 7
)
select dateSold,
  to_number(to_char(dateSold, 'D')) as d,
  to_char(dateSold, 'DY') as dy,
  to_char(dateSold, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') as dy_english
from cte;

and the same thing as if run in the USA:

DATESOLD          D DY               DY_ENGLISH  
-------- ---------- ---------------- ------------
01/08/18          3 MER.             WED         
02/08/18          4 JEU.             THU         
03/08/18          5 VEN.             FRI         
04/08/18          6 SAM.             SAT         
05/08/18          7 DIM.             SUN         
06/08/18          1 LUN.             MON         
07/08/18          2 MAR.             TUE
```

Notice that the day number and names/abbreviations are quite different, so trying to compare those against fixed values - whether `in (1, 3, 4, 7)` or using string-literal day names - wouldn't match reliably.

Forcing the date language to English makes the comparison safe. (Or any other language, of course - the string literals values just have to match the language you choose for the third argument to `to_char()`.)

Comment: so is there no way to do this without changing to varchar2? do you have anything that alludes to why oracle moved away from how they used to do it?

Comment: This is how they've always done it. There isn't an NLS-safe day number sadly. I don't believe there is a way without using strings, no.

Comment: Well... you *could* subtract your date from a fixed date that you know is a particular day of the week, and mod 7 it, which will give you a number from 0 to 6. And then interpret that however you need. That seems more work than string comparison though...

Comment: im already doing that to find thanksgiving.. if you know of a better way to find that it would be amazing

Comment: @UpTide - not sure what you're doing now, and completely off-topic; but (US) Thanksgiving for the current year is: `next_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY'), 10) + 20, 'THURSDAY')`. For any other year (from 1942) substitute `trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY')` with the first day of that year.

Comment: thanks, because this is getting negative im going to delete it. i hope you get to keep your karma. edit: i guess it wont let me.

Comment: If you don’t want to tamper with NLS settings, you can fake it with something like `mod(day+1,7)` which effectively rolls over the start of the week to another day. You can change the expression to something like `day+3` if you want to start in the middle of the week.